# Using CSS counters with columns

Tags: html, css

I work with long texts which I'd like to split into screen pages with columns.

I use CSS3 [column-width: 50vw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width) to set two columns per page and it works great (with `-webkit` prefix in webkit browsers). I fix the parent height to 100vh, so new columns are created as text grows, because `column-count` has its default auto value.

Now I'd like to display page numbers: [CSS3 counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) seem promising, but I don't know where to hook `counter-increment`.

Is there any way to use counters for that? The only solution I figured out is to lock the page scroll by whole pages only and to calculate the page number by the scroll position. Is javascript necessary here, or is there any pure CSS solution like using `nth-child` on columns?

**Edit**: To clarify, I added the following snippet to show how it works (for webkit browsers). Scroll right to show the third column.

```css
section {height: 500px; -webkit-column-width: 40vw; }
```

```html
<section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer mus Curabitur vitae Curabitur orci. Orci quis facilisi Nulla libero a volutpat Curabitur eget lacinia quis. Et nibh Pellentesque sollicitudin consectetuer sagittis auctor nulla Mauris justo felis. Urna vitae consequat nulla convallis non ligula suscipit hendrerit nibh Nam. Volutpat tortor odio auctor elit sed In ornare ridiculus.</p>
<p>Id Curabitur Sed justo laoreet id Sed platea Curabitur auctor semper. Nulla Aenean Nullam facilisis ac consequat Morbi ac Aenean nunc netus. Aliquam penatibus Curabitur risus felis tellus interdum id et Quisque at. Lacinia purus consequat sapien vel Curabitur turpis wisi senectus Nam parturient. Pellentesque sit et Suspendisse.</p>
<p>Et Curabitur orci quis et et semper Aenean Sed Suspendisse semper. Facilisis consequat Donec lacus at hendrerit est eget pulvinar id tincidunt. Neque congue consequat In Nunc dolor condimentum leo habitant eget tellus. Justo id Vivamus congue et semper nec montes consequat turpis nibh. Leo Maecenas dictumst et Vestibulum.</p>
<p>Sed Vestibulum Curabitur convallis Pellentesque vel rutrum Morbi metus sed pretium. Et pellentesque eros felis velit sagittis laoreet urna eu mauris quis. Phasellus orci Vivamus vitae congue convallis dictumst semper sem eget at. Id libero ut nunc Pellentesque convallis Donec Nunc congue porttitor porttitor. Sed quis ut quis Vestibulum eros id.</p>
<p>Sapien a Nullam amet et Morbi consequat urna enim molestie mi. Aliquam semper Sed dignissim mauris Aliquam dui et tincidunt suscipit Suspendisse. Curabitur amet mauris adipiscing cursus quis lorem parturient nunc hendrerit fames. Dui hendrerit gravida dolor pulvinar quis Suspendisse leo elit tortor nonummy. At natoque magna habitasse suscipit pretium odio eget vitae laoreet Vestibulum. Nam vitae Sed mus.</p>
<p>Donec amet quis id lorem et libero accumsan et mi et. Ipsum porttitor mauris turpis adipiscing hendrerit eget tempor tincidunt sed quis. Sed arcu Morbi Phasellus felis nunc vitae platea nec massa pellentesque. Wisi ante Maecenas netus Nulla eget id et Curabitur pede tristique. Nunc Nulla hendrerit neque vitae est justo lacinia Morbi Vestibulum justo. Magna.</p>
<p>Malesuada sed nisl ac malesuada justo netus nibh mauris malesuada Quisque. Risus urna dolor elit Vestibulum vitae elit consequat Nulla odio amet. Vel sagittis Vestibulum ipsum vitae enim consequat Integer id lacinia tellus. Id hendrerit Suspendisse Maecenas ac nibh sed.</p>
<p>Curabitur Vestibulum tortor turpis tristique Nunc congue Quisque justo habitasse pellentesque. Nunc netus quam tempor ac Nam iaculis ipsum velit mattis risus. Et et vel et dictum facilisis ipsum cursus congue rutrum dolor. Sed id gravida libero hendrerit nec Nunc id Cras tellus cursus. Eros lacinia est.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: As `column-width` does not actually make *pages* there's a lot of information missing from your question. I cannot tell you how to number pages if you don't explain how the pages magically appear out of nowhere.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes since `column-width` is 50vw, there are 2 columns per page. I hope there is some way to apply `:before` on specific CSS column, just like `nth-child` on table rows.

Comment: No, they don't. But my point was specifically that [just splitting text into 2 columns does not magically introduce the concept of pages](https://jsfiddle.net/dkcLmh3o/). As you can see in that sample, no notion of pages exist, just 2 long columns (as it should). You are missing vital info in your question.

Comment: Can you explain more? How do you split the long text into pages?

Comment: By letting `column-count` to default value (auto) and setting the height of parent element, new columns are automatically created as text grows (tested in Opera).

Comment: CSS counters count *elements*. Columns are not elements. Columns are just styling to divide your content in multiple columns. CSS counters do not apply to this behaviour. There may be a JavaScript solution, although I've never seen one.

Comment: I suspected you were setting the `height`, but that's vital info that was missing from your original post. Anyway, what you ask is not possible. @GolezTrol is not entirely right (you can trigger counters on more than just elements) but as columns do not exist in the DOM at any level, pseudo or real, you're out of luck. You can easily do this with JS tho, just divide scrollwidth by viewport width and add some absolutely positioned counters.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Strange, isn't it? Columns exist visually, but not in the DOM, I just hoped there is a trace about them somewhere on CSS level. Could you please just briefly explain how counters can be used on more than just elements?

Comment: They can be used on pseudo-elements too (`::before`, `::after`).

Comment: no, counter cannot be used here because only tags(includes pseudos related) can be used to increment